# How do I change a string line submitted in the form with another form input

Tags: php, string, forms, post, replace

In my first page I have this code:

```php
$number="1234567891";
$str="456";

echo "<form action='edit.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='msg' value='$message' />
        <input type='hidden' name='text' value='$number' />
        <input type='hidden' name='edit' value='$str' />
        <input type='submit' name='chedit' value='Go' style='position:relative; top:25px; left: 50%;'>
      </form>";
```

In my edit.php I have this code:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
   Edit Number
   <input type="text" name="change" value="$mumu"/>
   <input type="submit" name="pch" value="Change"/>
</form>

<?php
       if (isset($_POST["chedit"]))
       {
           $suj = $_POST["msg"];
           $text = $_POST["text"];
           $mumu =$_POST["edit"];
           if(isset($_POST["pch"]))
           {
               $change = $_POST["change"];       
               $obinna = str_replace("$change","$mumu","$text"); 
               echo $obinna;
           }
       }

     ?>
```

My problem is that whenever I put a new text in new form and click submit to edit a character in the old string submitted line the page refreshes and no result is output. Please can anybody sort this out?

Comment: all your code is in a condition `isset($_POST["chedit"])`, and you don't have an input named chedit, so it never enters the if.

Comment: Yes surpose **$_POST["chedit"]**
was submited from a diffrent ur?

Comment: Then the 1st time you load the page it will enter the if, but when you click on submit it only sends the data from the form.

Comment: What are you saying in hand this can not be acheve or yes?
Please state out your idea

Comment: To know if what you try to do can be achieved I would need to know what you are trying to do. What is this chedit and what is its purpose? What is the form supposed to do?

Comment: ohh i cant explain that in my case
$text = $_POST["text"];
return a string submited in the other url example 12345678910
and $mumu =$_POST["edit"];
has a string alist character of $text example 8910
looking out it can i use a new form to edit as i explain in my topic body above

Comment: @wapob, you change only " $obinna = str_replace("$mumu","$change","$text"); " this one in your code .

Answer (score 0):

//  try this ..

```
    if (isset($_POST["chedit"]))
       {
           $suj = $_POST["msg"];
           $text = $_POST["text"];
           $mumu =$_POST["edit"];
           if(isset($_POST["pch"]))
           {
               $change = $_POST["change"];   
                          //456 ,   //555(post value) , //(your text)12345678910
// $obinna = str_replace("Set old value you change in text","set new value you want to set in text ","your orignal text "); 
               $obinna = str_replace("$mumu","$change","$text"); 
               echo $obinna;
           }
       }
       echo '<form action="#" method="POST">
          Edit Number
          <input type="text" name="change" value="" placeholder="Change"/>
          <input type="text" name="edit" value="" placeholder="Edit"/>  
          <input type="submit" name="pch" value="Submit"/>
       </form>'
```

Check Demo Url :- https://eval.in/931366

Comment: in same page you display ?

Comment: $_POST["change"]; is a submit button and what is a  $_POST["msg"]; ??

Comment: Please post full code so we can help you .. Where is text and edit input box .?  $text = $_POST["text"]; and   $mumu =$_POST["edit"];

Comment: Check this url i hope it's helpful other wise pot you full code proper :- https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Comment: Yes i understand i can get it using my method couse my recent output we be clean for new form input maybe i try sending my recent output into a url or session before big thanks for your time