# how do I edit a character in string line with form input

Tags: php, string, post, replace

My code is given below I am trying to change a character in the string line with a new form input is here.

```
  $text = "12345678910";
       $mumu ="456";
       if(isset($_POST["pch"]))
       {
           $change = $_POST["change"];       
           $newtext = str_replace("$change","$mumu","$text"); 
           echo $newtext;
       }

   echo '<form action="#" method="POST">
      Edit Number
      <input type="text" name="change" value="change_now"/>
      <input type="submit" name="pch" value="Change"/>
   </form>
   </div>';
```

but i get **12345678910** return with no change please any one fixed this Thanks

Comment: What is your value for `$_POST["change"]`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this? Additionally if you're using single quotes `$mumu` won't be interpreted!

Comment: Remove those quotes in `str_replace()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// use this code ..

```
$text = "12345678910";
           $mumu ="456";
           if(isset($_POST["pch"]))
           {
               $change = $_POST["change"];       
                $newtext = str_replace("$mumu","$change","$text"); 
               echo $newtext;
           }

       echo '<form action="#" method="POST">
          Edit Number
          <input type="text" name="change" value="change_now"/>
          <input type="submit" name="pch" value="Change"/>
       </form>
       </div>';
```

=> For Demo :- https://eval.in/931363

Comment: yes but surpose $text and $mumu is a string submited from a diffrent url can this be achieve? Please see my recent question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121867/how-do-i-change-a-string-line-submited-in-the-form-with-another-form-input

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `$mumu` variable if you are changing value from `$_POST["change"]`.

Here, I am just giving you your example just for info as new value and old value.
This defines the when you are adding value with `$_POST["change"]`, it will give you new value of your textbox.

Hope this may help you.

```
$text = "12345678910";
/*$mumu ="456";*/
if(isset($_POST["pch"]))
{
     echo "old value = ".$text."</br>";
     $change = $_POST["change"];       
     $newtext = str_replace($text,$change,$text); 
     echo "new value = ".$newtext."</br>";
}

echo '<form action="#" method="POST">
      Edit Number
      <input type="text" name="change" value=""/>
      <input type="submit" name="pch" value="Change"/>
   </form>';
```